# How to build an existing gwt project via terminal

Tags: gwt, ant, build

I want to build the following [gwt tutorial project](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/files/gwt_hibernate_dto.zip)

I'm used to the gwt Eclipse plugin, so I'm at a loss when building an existing project via command line, I tried using the `ant build hosted` command from the downloaded project folder, [like the tutorial mentions](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/articles/using_gwt_with_hibernate), and got these errors:

```
  ant build hosted
    Buildfile: /home/antonio/Desktop/LABATI/MusicStoreDTO-NOECLIPSE/build.xml

    libs:

    BUILD FAILED
    /home/antonio/Desktop/LABATI/MusicStoreDTO-NOECLIPSE/build.xml:18: Warning: Could not find file /home/antonio/Desktop/LABATI/MusicStoreDTO-NOECLIPSE/C:/eclipse/plugins/com.google.gwt.eclipse.sdkbundle.win32_1.6.4.v200904062334/gwt-windows-1.6.4/gwt-servlet.jar to copy.

    Total time: 0 seconds


  [1]: http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/files/gwt_hibernate_dto.zipTI/MusicStoreDTO-NOECLIPSE/build.xml%20%20libs:%20%20BUILD%20FAILED%20/home/antonio/Desktop/LABATI/MusicStoreDTO-NOECLIPSE/build.xml:18:%20Warning:%20Could%20not%20find%20file%20/home/antonio/Desktop/LABATI/MusicStoreDTO-NOECLIPSE/C:/eclipse/plugins/com.google.gwt.eclipse.sdkbundle.win32_1.6.4.v200904062334/gwt-windows-1.6.4/gwt-servlet.jar%20to%20copy.%20%20Total%20time:%200%20seconds
```

I noticed the win32 required file.I'm working from an Ubuntu 12.04 box, is this source not buildable from non-Windows machines?

Answer (score 1):

Current release of GWT is 2.5 and `gwt-windows-1.6.4` has been outdated since 2009. You should follow a more up-to-date tutorial which refers to the latest (or at least a recent) version.